# Как задать обработчик кнопке в ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Здраствуйте, у меня есть listview состоящий из картинки,двух текстобоксов и двух баттонов. Как мне нужно расширитть simplecursoradapter чтобы я мог назначить обработчики на кнопки?(удаление элемента из базы и загрузка на сервер, если важно)

Comment: Скорее всего это делает через контекстное меню итема, так как я пытался создать чекбокс, и у меня переставал работать листвью как надо. По крайней мере я ни в одном приложении кнопок в листвью не видел никогда, это не естественно для этой среды. Можете ещё сделать свайп итема например, очень подходи для удаления. А нажатие на итем - загрузкой на сервер, как это сделано в Google Drive.

Comment: к сожалению это угробит красивый интерфейс( на зарубежных ресурсах видел какие то способы через задание тэга и переопределение getView но ни черта не понял

Comment: @mechanik0s - [button in listview item][1]

[1]: http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.it/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html

Comment: не могли бы вы объяснить как это работает?

Comment: точнее как оно должно работать,так как пример не выводит ничего и при попытке вставить значение вылетает с нульпоинтером